# unable to open files c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, codeblocks

I'm really struggling at the moment, originally had other issues with eclipse itself, that seems to have been resolved. Code looks right to me (compared to example code for loading files) however I'm not able to load anything as the error I put in is always triggered. No building errors atm. What am I doing wrong? Tried with both eclipse (mac) and Code::blocks (win vm), both seem to be having issues. the data files themselves are in the same folder as the .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Choose which data file to load (1-4)" << endl;
    int file;
    cin >> file;
    ifstream data;

    switch (file) {
        case 1:
            data.open("dataSet1.txt");
        case 2:
            data.open("dataSet2.txt");
        case 3:
            data.open("dataSet3.txt");
        case 4:
            data.open("dataSet4.txt");
    }

    if (!data) {
        cerr << "File not Loaded" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    string FullData[61];
    for (int i=0; i=60; i++){
        data >> FullData[i];
        cout << FullData[i] << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Got the program to stop showing the error, and it seems to be loading the files, however my assign/display loop doesn't seem to be working now as it displays only the last data point over and over again.

Comment: Written like that files need to be in the same folder as the _executable_, not the .cpp

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving the `break` statements out?

Comment: I am not sure if it causes a failure or not but in any case except `4` you are going to call open on the stream multiple times without ever closing the stream.

Comment: @Nacho It depends on the enviroment.  When using MSVS and not specifying a file path it looks in the folder that contains the source files.

Comment: @DariaD What compiler are you using and what does your environment look like?

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed, though I don't know how Codeblocks or Eclipse handle it, hence the comment

Comment: As per your edit... that's because your for loop is wrong: `for (int i=0; i=60; i++)` should be `for (int i=0; i<60; i++)`

Answer (score 4):

> the data files themselves are in the same folder as the .cpp file

Being in the same folder as the `.cpp` is not important, the dataset files should be in the same folder as the compiled binary program.

It can also be that there is a working directory setting that does not point on the directory where your dataset files are. All that is being passed into the `open` member function is a `string` which means that interpreting what that string means depends on the environment settings.

Comment: This looks like the true cause of the issue. The compiled program will take the string input of the `open` method and create an entry in the `.DATA` or `.TEXT` section of the executable. The final executable will have no knowledge of what the string actually means. The environment will help dictate to the program where to look to make sense of the provided string.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. In my case as @Gluk36 pointed, the problem was the working directory settings.

In that case, you must deselect "Use default settings" and set where the binary is. I attach you a screenshot for your reference from eclipse CDT 4.9 under linux.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You must have break statement after each case
like:

```
    case1://something;
          break;
```

and you must close the stream with close() function

```
    data.close();
```

Comment: This still wouldn't explain why the program fails to load the datasets.

Comment: added both those things in (breaks for each case) no difference, still won't load the file.

Comment: You havent specified a path @DariaD it must be like data.open("C:\Users\Desktop\dataset1.txt"); and do add data.close(); before return statement.

Comment: Man, expect nothing but downvotes if you just grab what's already commented in the question and use it as an answer.

Comment: Why does the OP have to call `close` at the end?  When the object is destroyed closed is called by the destructor so you are doing redundant work.